# Correct use of useReducer hook on multiple React components for Forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, jsx

So I'm having this project and it kills me with the way the instructions unfold step by step.
At first they asked me to create a BookingForm.js component that includes a form, for my app.
They asked me to use "useEffect" hook to manage the state in the component, and so did I.
Right after, they asked me to lift the state of specific element to another component, and pass the state down as props, to my BookingForm.js component.
And since I'm inexperienced with hooks and useReducer, I'm struggling so much to find the solution.
I feel I could make it work on my own, if it wasn't for this shift from useState to useReducer, because I don't know what to keep and what to change now.

This is my Main.js component that imports the BookingForm.js component and renders it.

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import ReactLogo from '../bruchetta.svg';
import image1 from '../greeksalad.jpg';
import image3 from '../lemondessert.jpg';
import image4 from '../restauranfood.jpg';
import image5 from '../customer1.jpg';
import image6 from '../customer2.jpg';
import image7 from '../customer3.jpg';
import image8 from '../customer4.jpg';
import image9 from '../restaurant.jpg';
import image10 from '../mario-and-adrian.jpg';
import { faStar } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import BookingForm from './BookingForm';


function Main() {

    function initializeTimes() {
        return [
          '17:00',
          '18:00',
          '19:00',
          '20:00',
          '21:00',
          '22:00'
        ];
    }

    const [availableTimes, dispatch] = useReducer(updateTimes, initializeTimes());

    const showBookingForm = false;

    function updateTimes(state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'update_times':
                return action.availableTimes;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {showBookingForm && (<BookingForm availableTimes={availableTimes} dispatch={dispatch}/>)}
            
         ...rest of my Main code...
        </div>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

And this is my BookingForm.js component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function BookingForm({ availableTimes = [], dispatch }) {
    const [date, setDate] = useState('');
    const [time, setTime] = useState('17:00');
    const [guests, setGuests] = useState(1);
    const [occasion, setOccasion] = useState('Birthday');

    const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Handle form submission logic here
        // e.g., display form data or make an API call
        console.log('Form submitted:', { date, time, guests, occasion });
    };

    const handleDateChange = (e) => {
        const selectedDate = e.target.value;
        setDate(selectedDate);
        dispatch({type: "update_times"}); // Dispatch the selected date to update available times
      };

    return (
        <form style={{ display: 'grid', maxWidth: '200px', gap: '20px' }} onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="res-date">Choose date</label>
            <input type="date" id="res-date" value={date} onChange={handleDateChange} />

            <label htmlFor="res-time">Choose time</label>
            <select id="res-time" value={time} onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}>
                {availableTimes.map((availableTime) => (
                    <option key={availableTime} value={availableTime}>
                        {availableTime}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>

            <label htmlFor="guests">Number of guests</label>
            <input type="number" placeholder="1" min="1" max="10" id="guests" value={guests} onChange={(e) => setGuests(e.target.value)} />
                <label htmlFor="occasion">Occasion</label>
                <select id="occasion" value={occasion} onChange={(e) => setOccasion(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
                    <option value="Anniversary">Anniversary</option>
                </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Make Your reservation" />
        </form>
    );
}

export default BookingForm;
```

At first when the website loads, I initialize the 'showBookingForm' = 'false' in Main.js, so that this component will not be displayed, and will only appear when the user clicks on any of the respective links.
When that happens, the rest of the Main component disappears properly.
But when I'm in my BookingForm, and the user tries to pick a date, it throws either of the errors :
"dispatch is not a function / initializeTimes is not a function"

with whatever attempt I tried.
What I want is for these instructions to be met by, but I can't:

"Step 1: Life state up to the Main component
As you added the table booking state to the BookingForm component in the previous exercise, in this exercise, you need to lift the state up to the Main component. This is the preferred approach in this case, as your app is relatively simple.

Move the availableTimes useState hook from the BookingForm component into the Main component

Pass down the state and state changing functions from the Main component to the BookingForm component using props in order to make state work across different components.

Step 2: Update BookingForm to display available times based on the selected date
The next step is to prepare the available times to be updated based on the date the user has selected. To do this, you will change the availableTimes state to a reducer.

In the Main component, create a function named updateTimes which will handle the state change. This function will change the availableTimes based on the selected date. For now, the function can return the same available times regardless of the date.

Next, create a function called initializeTimes which will create the initial state for the availableTimes.

Then, change availableTimes to a reducer using the useReducer function and provide the two previous functions as parameters.

Update the BookingForm component to dispatch the state change when the date form field is changed.

Tip: Include the newly selected date in the dispatch parameter."

Comment: Have they explicitly told you to use `useReducer`? Lifting state up doesn't necessarily involve that. All it means is a parent component maintaining the state and passing that state down to its child components, and you can still use `useState` for that.

Comment: @Andy yes my friend, they want me to do that. I can confirm it through different lines of their instructions, but as a fast reference, you can check the last line of my question, which is a tip they offer "Include the newly selected date in the dispatch parameter"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this solution will work for you or not, as I don't have the full code.

But, you can try with the following code.

Update the `Main.js` file like this, Pass handleDateChange function as props to update the selected date.

```
// Main.js

import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import BookingForm from './BookingForm';

function Main() {
  function initializeTimes() {
    return [
      '17:00',
      '18:00',
      '19:00',
      '20:00',
      '21:00',
      '22:00'
    ];
  }

  function updateTimes(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'update_times':
        return action.availableTimes;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }

  const [availableTimes, dispatch] = useReducer(updateTimes, initializeTimes());
  const showBookingForm = true; // Set to true to display the BookingForm component

  const handleDateChange = (selectedDate) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'update_times', availableTimes: initializeTimes() });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {showBookingForm && (
        <BookingForm
          availableTimes={availableTimes}
          handleDateChange={handleDateChange}
        />
      )}
      {/* Rest of your Main component code */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

And, Update the `BookingForm.js` like this.

```
// BookingForm.js

import React from 'react';

function BookingForm({ availableTimes, handleDateChange }) {
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState('');
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState('17:00');
  const [guests, setGuests] = React.useState(1);
  const [occasion, setOccasion] = React.useState('Birthday');

  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Handle form submission logic here
    // e.g., display form data or make an API call
    console.log('Form submitted:', { date, time, guests, occasion });
  };

  const handleDateChangeUpdate = (e) => {
    const selectedDate = e.target.value;
    setDate(selectedDate);
    handleDateChange(selectedDate);
  };

  return (
    <form
      style={{ display: 'grid', maxWidth: '200px', gap: '20px' }}
      onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
    >
      <label htmlFor="res-date">Choose date</label>
      <input
        type="date"
        id="res-date"
        value={date}
        onChange={handleDateChangeUpdate}
      />

      <label htmlFor="res-time">Choose time</label>
      <select
        id="res-time"
        value={time}
        onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
      >
        {availableTimes.map((availableTime) => (
          <option key={availableTime} value={availableTime}>
            {availableTime}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <label htmlFor="guests">Number of guests</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="1"
        min="1"
        max="10"
        id="guests"
        value={guests}
        onChange={(e) => setGuests(e.target.value)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="occasion">Occasion</label>
      <select
        id="occasion"
        value={occasion}
        onChange={(e) => setOccasion(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
        <option value="Anniversary">Anniversary</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Make Your reservation" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default BookingForm;
```

Now, when the user selects a date in the BookingForm component, the handleDateChange function will be called which is placed in the Main component. The Main component will handle the state update and update the availableTimes accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt, though the issue now is that the "handleDateChange" is being declared twice, as the error suggests.
Tried fixing it, it only gets worse, due to not knowing enough to do so.

Comment: I have updated the code, try again and let me know - If the issue, still persist.

Comment: Yes, this is the error I'm receiving when navigating to the BookingForm component now, through the respective route links.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Issue I think lies within the dispatch function.
Whenever I try to pick a date, it throws an  error, meaning it can't handle the state through dispatch.
And not considering it a function.

Comment: Okay, understood, But, I can't help by looking these components. You have to paste your  relevant code to pastebin or  somewhere else. I will look into it, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I just pasted it on pastebin, it's my first time posting there.
How should I share the bin to you so you can look into it?
Is sharing the link the appropriate way?
https://pastebin.com/tcaz9ppX

Comment: Yeah, I am able to see the pastebin. I will check your code and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: My friend I have fixed it, the issue was much larger and I realized it. Thank you!
It really was a huge mess due to the misleading instructions.
I took a different path earlier in the instructions, and while the code I wrote was 100% correct, then 5-6 steps later, what they were asking me to do, would just NOT work at all, no matter what.
Thank you for taking time to help me, I really appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of the project your clients/supervisers are trying to introduce new concepts to you one stage at a time which is a good technique. There are a couple of things I don't necessarily agree with (I'll explain later) but here's an example of how you might approach this.

1. It's important that you move the reducer logic outside of the component. First it maintains its own logic, and can be easily moved. More importantly it gets recreated every time the component is rendered which is not what you want. So you can move it outside the main component itself or, perhaps for better encapsulation, move it to its own file for export, and you can then import it into the component file. Here I've just moved it outside the component function.
2. I'm a little unsure about using `initialTimes` to populate the state because the time select only allows you to select *one* time. Far better to pass down a list of the available times to the component along with the state and dispatch.
3. On that last note - and I don't want to get ahead of your learning here - the next steps might be use `useContext` and bind the reducer to that. You won't have to pass down the state and dispatch function to the component because the component will have access to the context itself. But I'll leave that one alone for this exercise.
4. The initial state will look like this for your initial form values to work.

   ```
   {
     date: undefined,
     time: '17:00',
     numberOfGuests: 1,
     occasion: 'Birthday'
   }
   ```

   Note: you could set a initial date with [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) so that the date input would properly render the right date but I've left that for you to consider.
5. The reducer will have a series of cases that match how you want to update the state with the payload from the dispatcher. I won't replicate it here - you can see it in the code.
6. For convenience I've added a data attribute to each form input/select that you can use in the `handleChange` function. The function destructures the data attribute value, and the input value, and then uses those in the dispatch: `dispatch({ type: dispatchType, payload: value });`. I've done this so you don't need to create separate functions for each input.
7. I've included a `useEffect` so you can see the changes to state as you make the separate input selections. You should remove that from your final code.

There are a few bits and pieces I would change, and you may have to alter some of this to match the spec you've been given, but this should give you a good overview for now about how to proceed.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useReducer } = React;

function initialTimes() {
  return [
    '17:00',
    '18:00',
    '19:00',
    '20:00',
    '21:00',
    '22:00'
  ];
}

const initialState = {
  date: undefined,
  time: '17:00',
  numberOfGuests: 1,
  occasion: 'Birthday'
};

function reducer(state, action) {

  const { type, payload } = action;
  
  switch (type) {
    
    case 'updateDate': {
      return { ...state, date: payload };
    }
    
    case 'updateTime': {
      return { ...state, time: payload };
    }
    
    case 'updateNumberOfGuests': {
      return { ...state, numberOfGuests: payload };
    }
    
    case 'updateOccasion': {
      return { ...state, occasion: payload };
    }
    
    default: return state;
  
  }

}


function Example() {

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => console.log(state), [state]);

  return (
    <BookingForm
      state={state}
      dispatch={dispatch}
      availableTimes={initialTimes()}
    />
  );

}

function BookingForm({ state, dispatch, availableTimes }) {
    
    function handleFormSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('Form submitted:', {
        date, time, guests, occasion
      });
    }

    function handleChange(e) {
      const { dataset: { dispatchtype }, value } = e.target;
      dispatch({ type: dispatchtype, payload: value });
    }

    return (
        <form
          style={{
            display: 'grid',
            maxWidth: '200px',
            gap: '20px'
          }}
          onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
        >
          <label htmlFor="res-date">Choose date</label>
          <input
            type="date"
            id="res-date"
            value={state.date}
            data-dispatchtype="updateDate"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="res-time">Choose time</label>
          <select
            id="res-time"
            value={state.time}
            data-dispatchtype="updateTime"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {availableTimes.map((availableTime) => (
              <option
                key={availableTime}
                value={availableTime}
              >{availableTime}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <label htmlFor="guests">Number of guests</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="1"
            min="1"
            max="10"
            id="guests"
            value={state.guests}
            data-dispatchtype="updateNumberOfGuests"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="occasion">Occasion</label>
          <select
            id="occasion"
            value={state.occasion}
            data-dispatchtype="updateOccasion"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <option value="Birthday">
              Birthday
            </option>
            <option value="Anniversary">
              Anniversary
            </option>
          </select>
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Make Your reservation"
          />
        </form>
    );
}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This looks like a really interesting solution to my problem, I've tried to implement it exactly as you show it. Thought I'm facing the following issue:

Since I assumed you want me to remove the const variables I declared earlier for date, time, guests, occasion, that were using useState hook, It now gives me this error:

Line 8:13:  'date' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 8:19:  'time' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 8:25:  'guests' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 8:33:  'occasion' is not defined  no-undef

Am I doing something wrong? Thought they're declared in initialState

Comment: Did you update the value attributes too? `value={state.date}` for example. And yes, for this I did remove the useState's from the function because the state is held outside of the component. What you could do is keep those local useStates in that component, and only update the main state using a dispatch once you click the submit button. It depends on your requirements really.

Comment: Yes, I updated the value attributes as you suggested!
And as far as my knowledge suggests, it should work. 
1) You keep the state outside the Main component, it looks like it correctly gets passed as a prop to BookingForm, then I take it as a parameter, expecting that via state.date it understands what 'date' is, and won't throw the "date is undefined" error.
Still, it happens. Can't figure out why :/
Do I need to modify something?
You think we're missing something here?

Comment: Comment out `handleFormSubmit` and see what happens. Those errors are all appearing on the same line so that must be the issue (which makes sense).

Comment: It throws an error because right after, it gets called on this line:

<form style={{ display: 'grid', maxWidth: '200px', gap: '20px' }} onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>

Tried calling handleChange instead, doesn't load anything, still throwing undefined error

Comment: If you've commented out `handleFormSubmit` just remove `onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}`.

Comment: I really, really appreciate your effort my friend.
Still haven't solved this, though. I removed handleFormSubmit entirely, the values are correct, the copypasting is identical, still getting this error now:

Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'date')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'date')

Comment: A couple of things you could try: you've got a reference to `date` somewhere in your code - you could search for it/debug the code to find it and remove/update it depending on its context. You could add all the relevant code to https://pastebin.com/ and I'll take a look but I can't promise I'll get to it immediately.